# Sonarqube - Automating Permissions Templates

Tags: sonarqube

We are using an in house gitlab setup and teams can use a centralized sonarqube server for their scans.  However, we are faced with an issue where the users don't have access to their newly created projects.  We need a project template in place beforehand to create the proper permissions.  Is there any API in place for me to automate the creation of the project templates?

Ex) when a new project group is created in gitlab sync that over to a permissions template in sonarqube

Answer (score 2):

Use the [api/projects/create](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects/create) web service to provision your projects. You can then call [api/permissions/add_group](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/permissions/add_group) to grant group access to your newly provisioned project.